# Have Microsoft Word 2015 remember spelling and auto correct preferences

Tags: ms-office

How can I have Microsoft Word actually remember my settings for spelling and auto correct? I am using the Microsoft Word 15 (Preview).

I untick all these preferences every single time. Word refuses to remember the settings.

[image]

[image]

And every single time I reopen Word, they are ticked again.

Comment: Perhaps that feature is just missing from the beta version:-)

Comment: @TomGewecke Haha, it never even occured to me. It _is_ a preview I'm running.

Comment: I updated to a newer version of the Preview and now it works as expected.